# Regular database - MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MySql Datas;

```
   ID       Fname         Lname     
+------+-------------+-----------+
+  1   +    emre     +  surname  +
+  2   +    naMe2    +  suRnaMe2 +
+  3   +    namE3    +  SurnamE3 +
+ 1980 +    nAmE3    +  suRNamE3 +
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to:

```
   ID       Fname         Lname     
+------+-------------+-----------+
+  1   +    Emre     +  Surname  +
+  2   +    Name2    +  Surname2 +
+  3   +    Name3    +  Surname3 +
+ 1980 +    Name4    +  Surname4 +
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

How can I make the editing process? - Is it possible with SQL Query?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. http://whathaveyoutried.com, 2. learn about `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263272/capitalize-first-letter-mysql

Comment: This topic is already discussed here.
[Capitalize first letter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278207/mysql-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-existing-table

Comment: Even though unicode characters will behave as expected note that uppercase of `i` will become `I` (dotless i) and lowercase of `I` will become `i` if you go about using standard SQL case functions. If you have Turkish names there you might want to use some conditions in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simulating it,

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Fname, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(Fname FROM 2))) AS properFirstName,
       CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Lname, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(Lname FROM 2))) AS properLastName
FROM table1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43d01/1)

```
UPDATE tableName
SET Fname = CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Fname, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(Fname FROM 2))),
    LName = CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Fname, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(Fname FROM 2)))
```

Comment: The query succeeded, but the list does not change? Thank you for interest

Comment: yep because it is `SELECT` you didn't mention that you want to `UPDATE` the table, Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
UPDATE table
SET Fname = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(Fname, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(Fname, 2))),
    Fname = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(Lname, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(Lname, 2)));
```

This should be update all your value:

1. wOrld will become World
2. Help will remain Help
3. sEE YOU later1 will become See you later1

**I suggest you to try it on a backup table before to use it on the main one**.

Answer (score 0):

Check This is working .

First letter of a string to a capital

UPDATE `table` SET `field` = CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(`field`, 1)), SUBSTRING(`field`, 2))

and if you want to have all other characters lowercased:

UPDATE `table` SET `field` = CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(`field`, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(`field`, 2)))