# how to capitalise first character of the each word in a string using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE engine4_users 
SET displayname = CONCAT(
  UCASE(LEFT(displayname, 1)),
  LCASE(SUBSTRING(displayname, 2, INSTR(displayname, ' ')-1)),
  UCASE(SUBSTRING(displayname, INSTR(displayname, ' ')+1,1)),
  LCASE(SUBSTRING(displayname,INSTR(displayname, ' ')+2))
)
```

This is my query but the first two words of a string will be capitalised. More than two words are not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Capitalize first letter of each word, in existing table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278207/mysql-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-existing-table)

Comment: Jonathan's answer here shows how to split a string of arbitrary length, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql which you could then apply caps too, but arunrc has found an even better link.

Comment: This answer is not helpful to this question.I was tryed it.