# Capitalize first letter in all rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need a script to run that will update 'given_name' column and change all first letters to capital..

I currently have this code.. and nothing happens..

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CAPITALIZE;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE CAPITALIZE()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM users;
-- SET n = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users);
SET i=0;
WHILE (i<=n) DO 
  UPDATE users SET given_name = CONCAT( UPPER(SUBSTR(given_name,1,1)), SUBSTR(given_name,2)) WHERE user_id = n;
  UPDATE users SET last_name = CONCAT( UPPER(SUBSTR(last_name,1,1)), SUBSTR(last_name,2)) WHERE user_id = n;

  SET i = (i + 1);
END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4263289/1816093

Comment: I need to run the script in MySQL that will do the same function ..

Comment: How can I capitalize each first letter of each word.. @Drew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Drew mentioned, you might be better off just doing a blanket `UPDATE` statement for the entire `users` table:

```
UPDATE users
SET given_name = CONCAT( UPPER(SUBSTR(given_name,1,1)), LOWER(SUBSTR(given_name,2))),
    last_name = CONCAT( UPPER(SUBSTR(last_name,1,1)), LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name,2)))
```

To turn off your safe update mode, which is preventing the above query from working, type this:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Here is a working fiddle which demonstrates the above query:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3207/2)

Comment: I would suggest no while loop. Just do it directly in mysql. A single update stmt with set given, last

Comment: +Tim Biegeleisen - you got it right but when i run this script it still doesn't affect any rows or doesn't make any change

Comment: Please make your life easier and just use `UPDATE` as a query from your console.  Much easier, with a pleasant aftertaste.

Comment: Missed the other part of his while loop, sorry.

Comment: My senior told me to use stored proc, do you think my script above will work. but then thanks for the simpler version. I'm going to use that if I can change the settings on the main server.

Comment: @Drew can you help me to lower case the succeeding letters.

Example. data is : aSDvv.. must be converted to Asdvv

Comment: @EdwardBeringuela Just wrap the second `SUBSTR()` call with `LOWER()`.

Comment: What if the given name was TIM DREW what would it do.

Comment: I need to do it like Tim Drew sorry for my bad english

Comment: The query in my answer should handle the case `TIM DREW` and _any_ string, to get the format you want.  Try it out.

Comment: What it did was Tim drew, not Tim Drew.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen where is answer for Tim Drew xD

Comment: You should really open a new question.  This is substantially different than your original question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3278236/1816093  Now mark this Answer as correct with the happy Green check mark

Comment: It doesn't handle UTF-8 characters can you help me with it @Drew