# Capitalize first letter of multiple words of a column without CAP_FIRST

Tags: mysql, regex, uppercase

I have a table such as the below

```
    Name
    firstname lastname
    FirstName Lastname
    firstName Lastname
    FirstName lastname
```

I am trying to capitalize each letter of the `firstname` and `lastname` to be `Firstname Lastname` in all the 4 cases.

Any recommendations on the query without using the CAP_FIRST function? Can I use regex?

Comment: Why can't you use `CAP_FIRST`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Capitalize first letter of each word, in existing table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278207/mysql-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-existing-table)

Comment: From the examples you provided it looks like you're wanting to also convert all of the other letters to lowercase. This may not be ideal for `Firstname McLastname`, etc.

Comment: Yes, You got it right...need to lowercase the rest of the alphabets

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67399882/4227328), you can create the function to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a query that works:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,1,1)),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,2,Locate(' ', Name)-1)),
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+1,1)),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+2)))
FROM NameTable;
```

This the result:

```
Name
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
```

To UPDATE column use,

```
UPDATE NameTable 
SET NameTable.Name = CONCAT(
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,1,1)),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,2,Locate(' ', Name)-1)),
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+1,1)),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+2)));
```

Regards

Comment: Caveat: this will only do the first two words.  "first middle last" will result in "First Middle last".

Comment: Thank you..Yes, it works as the above comment specified- also I need to update the column..

Comment: It was required Firstname Lastname, not First Middle Last. To UPDATE see updated answer. It would be nice if you vote and/or accept di answer... and you practice a bit more with SQL. :)

Comment: This actually duplicated first letter of the first word for all rows without space, do not use!

Comment: Yes. It will make `WANDERER` to `WWanderer`. Do not use!

Answer (score 0):

**This is a fix of White Feather answer**,

The fix to avoid duplication of first character is to add IF condition in this part

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,1,1))
```

The original code is like this

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,1,1)),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,2,Locate(' ', Name)-1)),
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+1,1)),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+2)))
FROM NameTable;
```

Then updated version will be like this

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
    IF(INSTR(t1.firstname, ' ') > 0, UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,1,1)),''),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,2,Locate(' ', Name)-1)),
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+1,1)),
    LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name,Locate(' ', Name)+2)))
FROM NameTable;
```

But this only supports two words, if you have three or more it cannot be capitalized.