# Captalizing Each Word of an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'Artists'. There is a column called Artist in 'Artists'.

```
Artist
firstname lastname
Firstname lastname
Firstname Lastname
firstname
```

I tried the query on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071748/mysql-capitalize-first-letter-of-multiple-words-of-a-column-without-cap-first/36072804#36072804)

I want to captalize first letter of each artist's firstname & lastname in my 'Artists' table.
Expecting:

```
Artist
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
Firstname
```

Some of my Artists don't have firstname and the query is putting an extra character in beginning:

[image]

Comment: And why did that query not work for you? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Nick Some of the Artists don't have last names and its doing the following:[IMG](https://i.imgur.com/EhvNFmF.png) The query is putting a extra letter in the first name

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your question with the query you are using, and *all* the cases that don't work as you expect, and I will reopen it.

Comment: @Nick I added only two that came to my mind but there are way more Artists that only have first name and the query is putting an extra character in the front.

Comment: @Nick I already edited. Read the very last line of my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work around this issue is to use a `CASE` expression, choosing the formula from the other question when `Artist` has two names, and just capitalising the first letter when there is only one name:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Locate(' ', Artist) = 0 THEN 
         -- firstname only
         CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Artist, 1, 1)), 
                LOWER(SUBSTRING(Artist, 2)))
    ELSE
         -- firstname and lastname
         CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(Artist, 1, 1)),
                LOWER(SUBSTRING(Artist, 2, Locate(' ', Artist)-1)),
                UPPER(SUBSTRING(Artist, Locate(' ', Artist)+1,1)),
                LOWER(SUBSTRING(Artist, Locate(' ', Artist)+2)))
    END AS Artist
FROM Artists
```

Output:

```
Artist
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Lastname
Firstname
Firstname
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWPVjqQUfQknd3MFvQukKd/0)