# How to select uppercase of a name in particular column of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Example:

Table name : example with column Emp_name

```
emp_name    

Ron         
Raj         
Robert
```

I want to display the name `raj` in upper case for the table example.

Comment: only that one name with Upper case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3278207

Comment: That's a daft name for a table

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Remove the tag for the product not used.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I think you should write your query as follows:

```
SELECT UCASE(emp_name) FROM your_table WHERE emp_name = Raj;
```

If you want to select all the `emp_name` column and display it in uppercase, you should use this instead:

```
SELECT UCASE(emp_name) FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Either that or `SELECT CASE WHEN emp_name='Raj' THEN UCASE(emp_name) ELSE emp_name as new_emp_name FROM your_table`, if he wanted to return all names but only capitalise Raj

Comment: Is `UCASE()` MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: The UPPER function is used for SQL Server. Other SQL platforms may use the UCASE function.

Answer (score 0):

**Question is not clear whether you are asking for My sql**

use UPPER() for MS SQL Server