# Which SQL command should I use to organise upper case and lower case?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, uppercase, lowercase

Current **title** values under **article** table are, for example:

- Sample Title 1
- SaMpLE Title 2
- sample title 3

I have to change the first characters to upper case and the following characters to lower case.

They should be like below after the transaction:

- Sample title 1
- Sample title 2
- Sample title 3

Which SQL command should I use to change all data of the **title** using a MySQL query and change them **permanently**?

Comment: Then why did you tagged PHP. Do you want it to be done with PHP as an alternative

Comment: No, sorry. I removed the php tag.

Comment: change as in how, display or permanently? two different animals altogether ;-)

Comment: Well first you do a google for __mysql string function__ and then you get to this [page of the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) Then you read it, and decide which function best suites your needs. Then you test it until you get it right.

Comment: There's a function named [`LOWER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) for converting strings into lower and for making first word capital you can check [mysql-string-function-equivalent-to-php-ucwords-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866309/mysql-string-function-equivalent-to-php-ucwords-function)

Comment: I want to change them permanently.

Comment: The accepted answer does not use SQL as stated in the heading -- it uses PHP -> ```ucfirst($foo);```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ucfirst();` function in PHP.
By first retrieving it in a variable and then Pass it to a `ucfirst();` function and echo the answer.

```
<?php
  $foo = 'hello world!';
  $foo = ucfirst($foo);             // Hello world!

  $bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
  $bar = ucfirst($bar);             // HELLO WORLD!
  $bar = ucfirst(strtolower($bar)); // Hello world!
?>
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(title, 2)))' at line 1

Comment: @OnurAydın let me cross check.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this works:

```
CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(title, 2)))
```

Comment: Hope you dont mind I just added the LOWER to lower case all the other characters

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(title, 2)))' at line 1